# SoftwareBitmapEditor setPixel or getPixel switches colors

Tags: c#, uwp

Hi i was making some image processing for UWP using the SoftwareBitmapEditor class and after using it a bit with B&W images, but when I had switched to color images i realized that getPixel or setPixel aren't working properly. Am I doing something wrong or there is a big bug in the SoftwareBitmapEditor class? Why is the following code changing the colors in the image?

```
for (uint y = 0; y < _editor.height; y++)
{
    for (uint x = 0; x < _editor.width; x++)
    {
        var pixel = _editor.getPixel(x, y);
        _editor.setPixel(x, y, pixel.r, pixel.g, pixel.b);
    }
}
```

And this not

```
for (uint y = 0; y < _editor.height; y++)
{
    for (uint x = 0; x < _editor.width; x++)
    {
        var pixel = _editor.getPixel(x, y);
        _editor.setPixel(x, y, pixel.r, pixel.b, pixel.g);
    }
}
```

Even though this is the signature for setPixel

`public void setPixel(uint posX, uint posY, byte r, byte g, byte b);`

Comment: What is the `SoftwareBitmapEditor` class?

Comment: In case it's [this untested piece of software](https://github.com/TrevorDev/SimpleImageEditing/blob/master/SimpleImageEditing/SoftwareBitmapEditor.cs), have a close look at the [`getPixel`](https://github.com/TrevorDev/SimpleImageEditing/blob/master/SimpleImageEditing/SoftwareBitmapEditor.cs#L52) and [`setPixel`](https://github.com/TrevorDev/SimpleImageEditing/blob/master/SimpleImageEditing/SoftwareBitmapEditor.cs#L65) implementations, that conveniently flip the blue and green channels. That code cannot have been tested, ever.

Comment: @OP might be worth looking at something a bit closer to C#'s home, they have their own ability to manipulate pixels using the a PictureBox to display it, and a Bitmap object to draw it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404307(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @XtrmJosh: That's good advice, although for a UWP application the [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) class would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong or there is a big bug in the SoftwareBitmapEditor class?

I think this is a bug of this class.

> Why is the following code changing the colors in the image?

Before we use `setPixel` method, we need to get the pixel data of the `SoftwareBitmap` first using `getPixel` method. And you can refer to the [source code of this class](https://github.com/TrevorDev/SimpleImageEditing/blob/master/SimpleImageEditing/SoftwareBitmapEditor.cs), the `getPixel` method is like this:

```cs
public SoftwareBitmapPixel getPixel(uint posX, uint posY)
{
    var inputCurrPixel = desc.StartIndex + desc.Stride * posY + BYTES_PER_PIXEL * posX;
    SoftwareBitmapPixel ret = new SoftwareBitmapPixel();
    unsafe
    {
        ret.r = pixels[inputCurrPixel + 2];
        ret.b = pixels[inputCurrPixel + 1];
        ret.g = pixels[inputCurrPixel + 0];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

As you can see, the rgb order in the `getPixel` is different as it in the `setPixel`:

```cs
public void setPixel(uint posX, uint posY, Byte r, Byte g, Byte b)
{
    unsafe
    {
        var inputCurrPixel = desc.StartIndex + desc.Stride * posY + BYTES_PER_PIXEL * posX;
        pixels[inputCurrPixel + 0] = b; // Blue
        pixels[inputCurrPixel + 1] = g; // Green
        pixels[inputCurrPixel + 2] = r; // Red
    }

}
```

So here comes to your problem. One solution is as you did:

```cs
editor.setPixel(x, y, pixel.r, pixel.b, pixel.g);
```

Another method is:

```cs
editor.setPixel(x, y, pixel.r, b: pixel.g, g: pixel.b);
```

You can submit an issue on Github.

Comment: Neither of your proposed solutions can gracefully deal with a future bugfix. Unless a new member function is introduced for pixel manipulation, a bugfix will break this code. A better option would be to stop using this particular class altogether. The [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) class would be a starting point for a replacement implementation.

Comment: @IInspectable, yes you're right, so I suggested to submit an issue on github in the end. I thought it's the problem OP wanted to use this class and asked if this is a bug, of course we can focus on the basic image apis, it's definitely the right option.